# Pad number within string and rename file

Tags: bash, sed, rename

I have some filenames as such.

```
a2.txt.gz
d12.txt.gz
k5.txt.gz
m4.txt.gz
...
```

one character followed by 1 or 2 numbers followed by .txt.gz. I would like to add single numbers with a zero before the number like below.

```
a02.txt.gz
d12.txt.gz
k05.txt.gz
m04.txt.gz
...
```

I tried something like this but it doesn't seem to work.

```
find . | grep -E "[a-z][0-9]{1}\.+" | sed -er s/\([a-z]\)\([0-9]{1}\)\(.txt.gz\)/\10\2\3/
```

My logic was to first grep single digit filenames, then split into 3 parts character, number and .txt.gz and then add add 0 before number. But I can't get it to work. And I am not sure about the rename part.

Comment: `rename 's/(\d+)/sprintf "%02d", $1/ge' *.txt.gz`

Comment: I'm not convinced this is an exact dupe, as the linked question assumes a fixed filename prefix whereas this one is variable.

Comment: @EdwardFalk - it's not "an exact dupe" but _manatwork_'s solutions there should do (or _Gilles_' one, slightly modified: `zmv -n '([^0-9])([0-9]##).(txt.gz)' '$1${(l:2::0:)2}.$3'`)

Comment: @SatoKatsura The rename doesn't work for me.

Comment: You prolly have `rename` from `util-linux` which does not work with regex and has a different syntax.

Comment: There are (AFAIK) some three different versions of `rename` floating around. You need the Perl one, that comes with [Unicode::Tussle](https://metacpan.org/source/BDFOY/Unicode-Tussle-1.111/script/rename)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it like this:

`for f in [a-z][0-9].txt.gz;
do
  mv $f "${f:0:1}0${f:1}"
done`

I adapted this from something else (which used `awk` because it needed more, but thanks to a comment I made it better).

Comment: You don't need `awk` for this job, see my comment on OP's answer.

Comment: Updated answer as per that.  I hadn't seen your comment before I headed off to write my answer.  Seems our minds were running in the same gutter...

Answer (score 0):

This would do it:

```
find . -name '??.txt.gz' | sed -e 's/..\(.\)\(.*\)/mv \1\2 \10\2/' > /tmp/cmds
sh /tmp/cmds
```

The `find` command gets the list of files that need to be renamed. The `sed` command constructs a list of `mv` commands to do what you want. Those get written to a file and then executed as a shell script.

I'm sure there's a way to do this as a one-liner, but I'm feeling lazy.

Comment: But check to see if you have the version of rename on your system that takes regexes. If so, it will do what you want.

Comment: this doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Worked on my Mac, using the filenames you gave in your example. What part failed? Did you get /tmp/cmds? What was in it?

Comment: You could make it all one line by just piping int sh rather than writing the file.  Of course, then you couldn't ask the clarifying "what was in the file" comment.